# How to transfer an existing website to Google App Engine?

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

How can we go about transferring an existing wordpress website, with lots of images in wp-content/uploads folder.

I have been able to run a fresh wordpress install on GAE following this

> https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress

The part where I am stuck is how to transfer an existing website?

Comment: Are you going to use default app-engine data store?

Comment: nope, there no point in that, Google Cloud storage for static files, basically all the images that have been uploaded in the wordpress and are stored in wp-content/uploads folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will find a drag-and-drop way to transfer your current WordPress installation to AppEngine, at least not without a good deal of effort:

First, you need to manually create a migration/mapping from your current data store to an instance of CloudSQL.

Second, you need to (somehow) remap all the static files/images to either Blobstore or Google Cloud Storage as there are limits to the amount of static files you can upload to an App Engine app.

Third make sure all your existing plugins URL rules can be matched with AppEngine's routing mechanism.

Comment: First part is easy, an SQL file can be uploaded into the CloudSQL instance.

The second part is I'm concerned about. I can upload all the wp-content/uploads files to Google Cloud Storage, but I do go about re-mapping.

Well, third part has not created any such problems for now.

Comment: I beleive there was a WP plugin a while back, called WP CDN (or something like that) that would let you upload all your stuff to a CDN (Not sure if GCS was supported) and it would remap all links to that CDN.